# GWT Fileupload Using Servlet with GUICE

Tags: file-upload, guice, gwt-platform, guice-servlet

We are using GWTP with Guice.  I want to upload a file. For that I have written a Servlet.

I am using this [GWT File UPload Example](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~FileUpload). But Servlet is not getting called. I think its the problem with GuiceFilter.
Below is my web.xml entry.

---

### Web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.nextenders.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.nextenders.server.guice.actions.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>   
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload/fileUpload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any pointers would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem and solved on my own.
Here is the answer:

It was not the problem with the GUICE Servlet Filter.

The problem was with Coade statements placing. FileUpload `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload` should be used with FormPanel.

[FileUpload](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) must be used with FormPanel if it is to be submitted to a server.

I had used GWT file upload earlier but skipped thorough my mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Guice, you mush use Guice ServletModule class to set up your servlets.

Ex:
serve("/upload/pictures").with(PictureUploader.class);

Documentation:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule

Cheers,